# using expo and @react-native-community/async-storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm using `expo` to build and bundle my app. I've added [`@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install) but I get the following error on console:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" from "src/components/Message/Message.js"
```

my device also show multiple steps that might help to solve it as can be seen here
[image]

but unfortunately it didn't solve it.
I also tried:

- to clean `expo` cache folder from `~/.expo/`
- remove-re-install the Expo Client app
- clear the metro bundler cache in `/tmp` folder

I must say that when checking the `node_modules` folder, I've noticed that the package is installed under `@react-native-community` folder and not under `@react-native-async-storage` - but I can't be sure how those links magically happening under the hood, but maybe it worth to mention.

I saw in [`@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` docs](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install#link) that I need to run another `pod install` command but In `expo` the *platform-specific* folder is not accisible and the command runs without doing anything. Moreover, I've conducted [`expo snack` example](https://snack.expo.io/@zivl/76ca8b) but it functions properly. So probably something in my env or missing some configuration?

Any ideas?

Env details:

```json
"expo": "^38.0.0",
"expo-cli": "3.27.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.11.0",
```

Comment: Have you tried starting the packager with `--clear` option? According to `expo start --help` it _clears the Metro bundler cache_. Maybe Metro has cache in more places than only `/tmp`? 

Comment: @StanisławChmiela didn't help :(

Comment: clear cache `expo r -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing from `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` in your `Message.js` file try importing `@react-native-community/async-storage`.

This is the package you've installed, it was correctly installed under `@react-native-community` directory in `node_modules` as you noticed.

```
-import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
+import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Comment: i've tried that - the Expo Client app closes immediately once the component pops to screen - no errors on the console

Comment: There must be a different reason for that.  What device are you using to test the app? Are you able to reproduce the crash in Snack or a different project? Does the crash happen if you remove `AsyncStorage` code too?

Comment: when I switch the import statement and I debug - I see an error `"Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage"`

Comment: it happens both on my iphone 11 device and simulator. unfortunately, not yet reproduced on snack

Comment: 1. It looks like a warning that happens only if you import from `react-native`. That being said, it could be ignored if it blocks you and we can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: 2. When you talk about _switch the import statement_ do you mean _switching it to importing from `react-native`_ or _switching it to importing from `@react-native-community/async-storage`_? This warning should only appear if you import from `react-native` — I would encourage importing from `@react-native-community/async-storage` — this should not trigger the warning…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224146/discussion-between-stanislaw-chmiela-and-ziv-levy).

Comment: StanisławChmiela did you get my message on the chat?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running expo using:

`expo start --dev-client`

You likely need to rebuild your dev client.

If you're running using Expo GO it'll be linked automatically:

`expo start`